# Doctrine Migrations Postgresql Symfony generates empty migrations

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to make migrations based on a diff of my entities.
I'm expecting for the initial run (and following runs) that doctrine generates a migration with the diff.
I've tried the [following solution](https://gist.github.com/vudaltsov/ec01012d3fe27c9eed59aa7fd9089cf7) but this results in "No changes detected in your mapping information."
I've poked and went thru the doctrine migrations source code to see if I can extend/alter the behavior to no results. 
I also found related issues in doctine dbal like [this one](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/1110) and [this one](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/2490).

Is doctrine migrations still the way or is there another lib which is better suited for this problem?

I'm running PHP 7.4.4, Symfony 5.0.6, Doctrine Migrations 2.2.6 (latest stable), Postgres 12.1.

Doctrine config:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
    server_version: '12.1'
    charset: utf8
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    dbname: storage001
    default_dbname: storage001
```

Entity example:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(schema="storage001", name="entityName")
 */
class EntityClass1
{
...
}
```

Comment: I was dissatisfied with doctrine migrations diffs for a long time and always implemented migrations myself - still with doctrine-migrations, but "manually" writing the migrations while extending the AbstractMigration to better suit the needs the Schema/Table/Column classes wouldn't comfortably provide. isn't public though ;o/ but worked nicely (conceptually)

Comment: Yeah the diff has always been a pain. Well then I'll just manually write them too :)